# Error:(42, 16) error: incompatible types required: Loader<List<String>> found:FileLoader

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the `LoaderManager` in my code however I'm getting an incompatible types error:

```
      @Override
      public Loader<List<String>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
         return new FileLoader(MainActivity.this);
      }
```

shouldn't this statement `return new FileLoader(MainActivity.this)` returns a Loader? And here is the implementation of the **LoaderManager**:

```
     public class FileLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<String>>{

       public FileLoader(Context context){
          super(context);
       }

       @Override
       public List<String> loadInBackground() {
          .........
          ........             
          return listFiles;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem(incompatible types required), but when  see your post ,it helps me to learn more.In my code, it was imported:

"import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader;"

, so  i change it to:

"import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;"

then my problem solved.
Because "AsyncTaskLoader" : This class was deprecated in API level 28,by below ref.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader

by this advice,"You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX", the webpage below:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

Answer (score 0):

finally I succeeded to solve the problem ... it was that didn't Import the support  library in the AsyncTaskLoader file , while using it at the Main file ...so i just removed

```
    import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
```

and Import the following support library

```
    import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
```